# Display all Microsoft Forms in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions, microsoft-graph, microsoft-forms

We have few Microsoft Forms & Quizzes created on [Forms Platform](https://forms.office.com/).

Is it currently possible to display all of the Forms and Quizzes in SharePoint Online?

For example I want to display all of the Forms inside my SharePoint using some custom CSS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, there is currently no OOTB way to display all Microsoft Forms in SharePoint Online.

We suggest that you can go to **[the Microsoft Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/ct-p/SharePoint)** to submit a feedback.

**Here I provide a workaround for your reference:**

1.Navigation to the **[Forms Portal](https://www.office.com/launch/forms?auth=2)** as a global administrator

[image]

2.On this page you can see the number of Forms for each site

[image]

3.Here is my test:

[image]